# how to convert the undefined to string in TestCafé?

Tags: javascript, string, testing, e2e-testing, testcafe

Need to convert the Selector's attribute into string. So, that I can take the particular portion of the id's text.

```
 async getTitleID(TitleName){
     var TitleID = Selector('span').withText(TitleName);
     console.log(TitleID);
     var getTitleID = await TitleID.getAttribute('id');
     console.log(getTitleID);
     var getTitleIDStr = (getTitleID.toString());
    // if( getTitleID!=null ){
    console.log(getTitleIDStr);
    var Title = getTitleIDStr.substring(40, 51);
    console.log(Title);
    // }
    return Title
 }
```

I got the error code: **1) TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't convert 'undefined' to string or anything. 'Undefined' is a result of the toString() method call which returned 'nothing' and this 'nothing' does not have the 'substring' method. I recommend that you debug your test case code to see what's going on: [Debug Tests](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/debug-tests/).